# For $z=a+bi$, $z\in\mathbb{C} $, find the complete set of values of $Arg(z)$ if the principle argument of $Arg(z^3)$ is in the second quadrant

Tags: complex-numbers

Question :

> For $z=a+bi$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$, find the complete set of values of $Arg(z)$ if the principle argument of $Arg(z^3)$ is in the second quadrant.

My Working :

> If $Arg (z^3)$ is in the second quadrant $\theta=\frac\pi2\to\pi$
>  
>   Let $|z| = x$
>   $z^3=x^3cis\theta$ 
>   $z=xcis\frac\theta3$
>   $Arg(z)=\frac\pi6\to\frac\pi3$

Was just wondering if someone could confirm that answer and working is correct and if not where I went wrong?

Comment: What if the argument of $z$ lies between $\frac{5\pi}6$ and $\pi$?

Answer (score 1):

If we are given a complex number $w=r\,e^{i\phi}\ne0$ there are three complex numbers $z$ satisfying $z^3=w$, namely
$$z_-={\root 3\of r}\,e^{i(\phi-2\pi)/3}, \quad z_0={\root 3\of r}\,e^{i\phi/3},\quad z_+={\root 3\of r}\,e^{i(\phi+2\pi)/3}\ .$$
Since we are told that ${\pi\over2}<\phi<\pi$  these three numbers have (principal values of their) arguments in the following ranges:
$$-{\pi\over2}<{\rm Arg}(z_-)<-{\pi\over3},\qquad {\pi\over6}<{\rm Arg}(z_0)<{\pi\over3},\qquad {5\pi\over6}<{\rm Arg}(z_+)<\pi\ .$$